# How can I fix my door frame

Tags: door-frame

So yesterday I accidentally locked my bathroom door so I had to kick in the door and now a piece of my door frame came off (the door still closes and is fully functional ) I wanted to know how I can fix this or what supplies you recommend I could get at Home Depot to put the broken piece back in

[image: The Door Frame]

Comment: I suppose nobody told you that you can unlock most interior door locks without force?

Comment: I think we watch too much TV. "Just kick the door down".

Comment: You can use a banana ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI5mSuSLoSc)) or toothpaste ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqNmQdWg09I)) to unlock the door!

Comment: @BenWelborn only if the door hasn't seen the Monty Python self-defense video.

Answer (score 1):

To do it right a new piece of trim that matches or 3 new ones around the inside would be a start. An over sized strike plate (the part the latch drops into) and a couple of longer screws to secure the strike plate. Then find a small flat blade screwdriver to keep close in case this happens again. Most of these doors have a small hole in the outside knob. With the door open practice unlocking it. Some only need to push the button out, some you need to turn to get them to unlock.

Comment: Either a flatblade or a short length of approx. 1/16" wire - many knobs unlock with a skewer-like object that you just push in, as opposed to twisting the flatblade.